# Drupal multisite setup with suExec/suPHP and symlinks

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, cpanel, suphp, suexec

I want to have one Drupal copy to maintain, but a lot of sites running from that copy.

I'm using cPanel to create users and add bandwidth and disk space limits, therefor I need to place uploads within the cPanel user's home dir.
A user's site config should not be viewable by other users, therefor I do believe I need to use some kind of suExec or suPHP.

This is the guide I've tried following: http://drupal.org/node/1274642

Basically I have a frontend where a user enters a subdomain and then via a cPanel API I create a user for that subdomain and add limits for bandwidth and disk space.

Can anyone help creating this setup?
I've been thinking about making a symlink from /home/dp1234/public_html to /path/to/drupal/copy, but then everyone would be able to view the setting files in Drupal's sites folder - I think?

I keep getting weird permission problems. I got it working a couple of times but all of the sudden it didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out why it wasn't working.
It was an Apache configuration thing that was checked true: [x] SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

I unchecked that and finally everything started to work!